# CakePHP - SMTP Error : 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

Tags: email, authentication, cakephp, outlook

I'am using cakePHP 2.0 version, While sending mail I get error as below.

> SMTP Error: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

config/email.php

```
public $SendMail = array(
    "SMTPAuth"  =>true,
    'SMTPSecure'=> 'tls',
    'host' => 'outlook.office365.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'transport' => 'smtp'
   );
```

If I user the same in PHPMailer its working fine.

In php version 5.6.30 its not working, Same configuration is working fine in version 5.5.38. What might be the issue?

I already referred few links given below. Which doesn't work for me.

1)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809816/cakephp-send-mail-through-smtp-to-ms-outlook-smtp-error-504-5-7-4-unrecogni

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939427/change-cakeemail-smtp-authentication-type